# Two-way unread flags synchronisation using IMAP

Tags: node.js, outlook, imap

I'm using [node-imap](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap) but apparently some (most?) servers do not send the update notification reliably (gmail and outlook at least don't).

I know there's RFC4551 (CONDSTORE) but e.g. Outlook doesn't support that. Is there any way to keep the `seen` flags in sync (other than fetching all unread messages and comparing them to what I last saw)?

Answer (score 0):

No. Condstore is that way.

Condstore was developed speficically to solve your problem. If there had been another answer already, the work on condstore would not have been necessary.